# SML Comparing datatype list and hd() tl() function

Tags: smlnj

For 2 datatype like this.

```
datatype flight = F of int * int; 
datatype flights = Fs of flight list;
```

I want to make a function that can check if (a,b) is in flights or not.

Example:

```
val reachable = fn : flights * (int * int) -> bool

reachable (Fs [F(0,1), F(1,0)], (0, 1));
val it = true : bool
```

I have no idea how can i compare a (int*int) to flights.

I use

```
fun get_f_x (F(x,y)) = x;
```

to get the first integer in flight.

But when i try to do the same thing to flights.

I do it like below:

```
fun test_hd(Fs[i,_]) = i;
```

In order to get the first flight out for the flights.
But it can only take flights with 2 flight only (Fs [F(0,1), F(1,0)])
If flight have more than 2 element, it show error.

Similarly

```
fun test_tl(Fs[_,i]) = i;
```

have the same problem.

How can I make a hd and tl for flights? Or what is the correct way to think about this problem?

Comment: A list specified using `[` and `]` in a pattern is a match for exactness. For example, a pattern like `F[x]` will match for a list with exactly 1 element, `F[x, y]` will match for a list with exactly 2 elements, ans so on and so forth. However, we can specify a pattern to match any list using `F(x::ys)` construct, except for `Empty` list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not having seen the errors you're encountering, it's hard to say, but looking at the code you've shown, I suspect in-exhaustive pattern matching is a factor. With that in mind, let's look at a way of breaking down the recursion and pattern matching involved.

If you want to see if a particular flight is in flights, first we need to start with what we absolutely know: If a `flights` value contains no values in its list, then the answer must be false, no matter what we're looking for.

```ml
fun reachable(Fs([]), _) = false
```

What if there is something in that list? Well, let's check the first element to see if it's what we are looking for.

```ml
fun reachable(Fs([]), _) = false
  | reachable(Fs(F(x) :: xs), flt) = flt = x
```

But what about the rest, if that one doesn't match? We'd need to check the rest of the list.

```ml
fun reachable(Fs([]), _) = false
  | reachable(Fs(F(x) :: xs), flt) = 
      flt = x orelse reachable(Fs(xs), flt)
```